# Set TextField text as data in TableView Column

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm creating a Java application using the MVC model (FXML files and controller classes). In one of the scenes, there is a TableView, with a column called ID which holds the Volunteers' IDs, according to data in the SQL database. I need to get the Volunteer ID from this column and set the text of a TextField in the next scene as this ID. I also want to be able to use the value of the ID to access data from a particular tuple from the database table. How can I do this? Right now, the TextField in the next scene is just showing 0 every time.

PFB the code of the two controller classes. Forgive me if I'm doing this completely wrong—I'm really new at coding.

View All Volunteers Controller (the scene with TableView)

```
public class ViewAllVolsSceneController implements Initializable  {

    @FXML public TableView <Volunteer>tableviewAllVols;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Volunteer, Integer>colID;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Volunteer, String>colForename;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Volunteer, String>colSurname;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Volunteer, String>colDepartment;
    @FXML public TableColumn <Volunteer, String>colSkill;
    @FXML public Button btnBack;
    ObservableList<Volunteer> volData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public int selectedVolID;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        
        try {
            Connection conn = driver.connector();
            String query = "SELECT volunteerID, forename, surname, deptName, skill FROM volunteers inner join departments"
                    + " on volunteers.deptID = departments.deptID";
            
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                volData.add(new Volunteer(rs.getInt("volunteerID"), rs.getNString("forename"),
                        rs.getNString("surname"), rs.getNString("deptName"), rs.getNString("skill")));
            }
            
        }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    colID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("volunteerID"));
    colForename.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("forename"));
    colSurname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("surname"));
    colDepartment.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("deptName"));
    colSkill.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("skill"));
        
    tableviewAllVols.setItems(volData);

}

    public int doubleClickRow() {
        tableviewAllVols.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
                    if(event.getClickCount() > 1){
                        
                        try {
                        Parent volFormParent;
                        volFormParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("volForm.fxml"));
                        Scene volFormScene = new Scene(volFormParent);
                        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                        window.setScene(volFormScene);
                        window.show();  
                                            
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
        
                        }
                    }
                });
        return selectedVolID;
        
        }

public void selectedVolID () {
    
    selectedVolID = tableviewAllVols.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getVolunteerID();
}
```

Volunteer Form Controller (the scene with the TextField that I need to fill using data from the ID column of the TableView)

```
public class volFormController implements Initializable {

        @FXML public TextField txtForename;
        @FXML public TextField txtSurname;
        @FXML public TextField txtSchool;
        @FXML public TextField txtEmail;
        @FXML public TextField txtPhone;
        @FXML public ComboBox<Department> comboboxDept;
        @FXML public DatePicker datepickJoin;
        @FXML public ChoiceBox<String> choiceboxSkill;
        @FXML public Button btnSave;
        @FXML public TextField txtVolID;
        @FXML public Button btnCancel;
        
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        
        
        ViewAllVolsSceneController selectedVol = new ViewAllVolsSceneController();
        txtVolID.setText(Integer.toString(selectedVol.selectedVolID));

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set text of TextField using data from TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788444/set-text-of-textfield-using-data-from-tableview)

Comment: same error as in your last (identical) question ... work through a tutorial on how to use fxml - and stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: @kleopatra my question was partially answered. i was getting an exception, which i've now fixed, but i still don't know how to set the text of the TextField as data from a column from my TableView. and yes, i have watched many tutorials on FXML but none of them (the ones i've seen, at least) seem to answer this question

Comment: re-read my comment in the previous and do as it suggests .. what you are trying to do is completely wrong, because you don't seem to understand the basic mechanics of how fxml is working (the only reason it's not throwing a NPE this time is that you access an int - with default value 0 - vs an object - with default value null). btw: note the difference between _watching_ a tutorial vs. _working_ through a tutorial ;)

Comment: @kleopatra ahh, okay. thanks!

Comment: @khushi FXML tutorials aren't the issue here.  You've got basic coding errors unrelated to FXML.  doubleClickRow() is odd, it isn't called when the row is double clicked for example

Comment: @swpalmer agreed: there are more basic errors than the incorrect access of a controller - let's assume, they are all fixed and selectedVolId (in ViewAllXXController) really reflecting the id of the selected item in the table  and being != 0: the text of txtVolId in the other controller will still be "0" ;)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have several issue here, you aren't updating the value returned by this:

```
return selectedVolID;
```

and more specifically - why are you returing that value in a method that simply installs a listener?

Inside the click listener you should be calling the method to updated the value:

```
selectedVolID();
```

and you should change the names so things aren't so confusing.

You should really set some breakpoints and step through your code.  I don't think it is doing what you think it is doing, and stepping through is the best way to figure that out.